# INSERT в PostgreSQL 9 для связанных данных в одном SQL запросе

Tags: postgresql, postgresql9.6

Есть таблица t1 с id и data.
Есть таблица t2 c id, t1_id и data.
Есть таблица t3 с t1_id c data.

Мне нужно сделать следующие запросы:

```
with new_t1 as (
    insert into t1 (data) values ('test data') returnning id
)

insert into t2 (t1_id, data) values (select id from new_t1, 'Test data 1'), (select id from new_t1, 'Test data 2');


insrt into t3 (t1_id) values (--- Как мне получить здесь t1.id из первого insert?)
```

Поясню, что это.
Мне нужно создать .sql файл, в котором заносятся данные в 3 связанные таблицы через t1.id. С помощью with я могу сделать insert в две таблицы, но как мне узнать t1.id в третьем запросе?

Comment: CTE позволяет использовать несколько объявлений, так что `with new_t1 as( insert t1 returning ... ), new_t2 as( insert t2 returning ....) insert into t3 ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В одном запросе может быть несколько CTE, ссылающихся друг на друга.

```
with new_t1 as (
    insert into t1 (data) values ('test data') returning id
),
new_t2 as (
    insert into t2 (t1_id, data) values ((select id from new_t1), 'Test data 1') returning t1_id
)
insert into t3 (t1_id, data) values ((select t1_id from new_t2), 'Test data 2')
```

Comment: Это работает превосходно. У меня почему-то не выходило использовать new_t1 во втором выражении with. Спасибо.